# Is it possible to use the NatTable component from SWT to JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, swt, nattable

I would use the NatTable component that is available in SWT to my JavaFx project. In case it is possible, how do we do it?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to use SWTonFX
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse#SWT_on_JavaFX

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to congratulate you for the work on your component. I will try what you told me.

Comment: I looked at the method.I don't try to migrate a swt project in JavaFx. I have a javafx project or I want to use NatTable to display my data.If possible, how?

Comment: NatTable is a SWT control. Either you include SWTonFX in your JavaFX setup or it is not possible right now.

Comment: Ok.Thank you for your answer